# How check each query param individually in angular 6

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular6

I'm facing a problem to handle query params in my angular application. I have multiple query params in my search page. Below is the url

> /search?q=hyderbard&view=map&type=bat&brand=sg

```
const urlParams = Observable.combineLatest(
      this.route.params,
      this.route.queryParams,
      (params, queryParams) => ({ ...params, ...queryParams })
);
urlParams.subscribe(routeParams => {
     routeParams.q !== undefined ? (this.q = routeParams.q): (this.q = "Bangalore");
     routeParams.type !== undefined ? (this.type = routeParams.type): (this.type = "All");
     routeParams.view !== undefined ? (this.view = routeParams.view): (this.type = "list");
     // this will call search api
     this.getList();
});
```

This is my code, so whenever query params get changed, `getList` is called. 
I don't want getList to be called when view query param updated. How to do this? Can any one please help

Comment: store the value and compare it?

Answer (score 0):

```
urlParams.pipe(
 tap((routeParams) => {
  routeParams.q !== undefined ? (this.q = routeParams.q): (this.q = "Bangalore");
  routeParams.type !== undefined ? (this.type = routeParams.type): (this.type = "All");
  routeParams.view !== undefined ? (this.view = routeParams.view): (this.type = "list");   
 }),
 map((routeParams) => {
   const {view, ...rest} = routeParams;
   return rest;
 }),
 distinctUntilChanged((prevParams, curParams) => JSON.stringify(prevParams) === JSON.stringify(curParams))
).subscribe(() => {
     this.getList();
});
```

should do that

Comment: what do you mean by not working? is it showing any errors or behaves wrong?

Comment: no error, still this.getList() is called when view is updated